# extjs4 : chained combo

Tags: combobox, extjs4

I'm trying to add some dynamic data into a "livesearch" combo box.

I've a set of 2 combos.

The first one allow you to select some data.
The second combo is a "livesearch" combo that should have a dynamic parameter from the first combo.
So the 2nd combo is linked to a model, which is linked to a datastore that queries the server and outputs the data. But that data has to be filtered according to the first combo parameter...

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I did that [before](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase#LinkedCombos). The key is to pass the value of the first combo with the request for the values of the second combo, and then filter the results on the server. Other approach would be to load both combos with all possible values and then set a filter on the second combo's store after a value is selected in the first combo.

**EDIT**: Here's the I used.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.FilteredCombo', {
extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
alias: 'widget.filteredcombo',

queryCaching: false,

getParams: function (queryString) {
    var params = this.callParent(arguments);
    if (Ext.isArray(this.formParams)) {
        var form = this.up('form');
        if (form) {
            var bf = form.getForm();
            for (var i = 0; i < this.formParams.length; i++) {
                var field = bf.findField(this.formParams[i]);
                if (field)
                    params[this.formParams[i]] = field.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return params;
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, passing the value of the combo to the request made by the datastore is what I want.

I can get the combo value, I can fetch data from the server into the datastore, but I can't dynamically update the datastore parameters when the user starts to input text into the combobox.

I can reload a datastore with new params when a user clicks on something for example, because I handle myself the store reloading, but the store reloading is probably handled by the combo. I <could> rewrite that part of the code, but that would be fugly...

Comment: To solve reload issue add queryCaching: false on your store config. Also, I added the code I used in my example.